# VBA code that clears filter on pivot table on exit of worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clear a pivot table filter on exit of that sheet.

I've googled and found nothing that works or is similar to what I'm trying to do.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_deactivate()

    Call ClearFilter

End Sub

Sub ClearFilter()

' ClearFilter Macro

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[DIM Material Master].[Material Group].[Material Group]").ClearAllFilters
End Sub
```

When I run it I get a Run-time error 1004, Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class.

Comment: If you've deactivated the sheet, it's no longer the `ActiveSheet`. Change `ActiveSheet` to the sheet the pivot table is actually on.

Comment: Thanks BigBen, how do I call out the sheet? I'm pretty new to vba and mostly use macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've deactivated the sheet, then it's no longer the `ActiveSheet`. Change `ActiveSheet` to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("yoursheetname")` to reference the worksheet the pivot table in question is on.

Another option is a bit simpler:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_deactivate()

    Me.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[DIM Material Master].[Material Group].[Material Group]").ClearAllFilters

End Sub
```